# Task Status out of sync with actual Status sharepoint 2010

Tags: designer-workflow

I have a Workflow that Collects Data from a user.  The problem is, the workflow isn't continuing/updating the status/outcome of the actual workflow once the task is completed.

The workflow looks like this:

[image]

And once the Collect Data task is completed, this is what appears in the Task Status page, see how the status is out of sync with itself?  This also means the workflow is "stuck". It won't continue to closure, and I have to Terminate it!  Help!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We had a simular issue. There was an error during the re-hydration proces, the workflow threw an exception on the de-serialization proces due to use of a non serializable property/field on the workflow class, in our case the nhibernate session factory.